# Python: Removing list with repeated elements in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists as follows:

```
seq = [[2, 5], [1, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 5], [2, 3], [3, 5], [1, 1], [2, 4], [1, 3]]
```

How do I remove the list inside this list which have repeated elements i.e. `[1, 1]`?

Comment: Giving only one example of what is considered a "repeated" element is bad practice. Which of the following sublists is considered as being suitable for removal: [], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2]

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case:

```
[i for i in seq if i[0] != i[-1]]
```

More generally, remove sublists where all items are equivalent (kudos @A-B-B 8' comment):

```
[i for i in seq if len(set(i)) > 1]
```

Finally, if any replicates are found within a sublist, e.g. `[..., [1, 2, 2]]`:

```
import collections as ct

[i for i in seq if i and all(v == 1 for v in ct.Counter(i).values())]
```

---

Tests using the final solution:

```
def drop_replicates(seq):
    return [i for i in seq if i and all(v == 1 for v in ct.Counter(i).values())]


assert drop_replicates([[2, 5], [1, 1], [2, 4]]) == [[2, 5], [2, 4]]
assert drop_replicates([[2, 5], [1, 1], [2, 4], [1, 2, 2]]) == [[2, 5], [2, 4]]
assert drop_replicates([[2, 5], [1, 1], [2, 4], [1, 2, 2], []]) == [[2, 5], [2, 4]]
```

Comment: To make it more general, use
`[i for i in seq if len(set(i) != len(i)]`

Comment: For the `set` technique, there may be a reason to use `>` rather than `!=`. This is because `>` will also remove empty sublists. It can perhaps be asserted that all elements of an empty list are equal.

Comment: @Roopak I think you mean `==`.

Answer (score 0):

`set(i)` converts the list to a set. Sets are unordered lists without duplicates (same as mathematical sets). Following is a more generic solution, it should work with any number of elements in the child lists.

```
[i for i in seq if len(set(i)) == len(i)]
```

Comment: Try ` ==` and you are missing a `)`

Comment: I used `!=` to remove the duplicate items.

Comment: `!=` is actually keeping the duplicates.  You want the opposite, where the length of the set equals the sublist length.  This means the sublist has unique elements.